# markAsPristine() not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, formgroups

After saving the object I want to make my `formGroup.Dirty` property `false`, so I used the **markAsPristine()** function.

```
formGroup.markAsPristine().
```

Checking `formGroup.Dirty` property using Chrome, Edge and FireFox, it is set to `false`.

But When I checked it on **IE11**, the Dirty property still `true.`

How can I make sure that the Dirty property is set to `False` on **IE11** ?

Comment: did you got your answer ?

Comment: It was an IE11 issue. I updated the IE11 and  the problem was solved.